# How to animate this slider?

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, jquery-animate, slideshow

Hello everyone I did a slider and it works fine, but I want to animate slide when i click arrows. There is my code: [Code](http://jsbin.com/UCafIhis/10/edit)

Comment: slide to the side or fade?

Comment: not relevant just don't know how to do it

Comment: It is relevant because the 2 effects require different architecture of the plugin. It's not as simple as slapping 'slide' or 'fade'... Check this out: http://paulmason.name/item/simple-jquery-carousel-slider-tutorial

Comment: I want to move between slides

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery transit plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

For example (500ms animation with easeOut..):

```
$("li").transition({ x: -700 }, 500, 'easeOutExpo', function() {

  // Transition completed

});
```

That is really good plugin and it supports CSS3 transitions.